# Memcache working in production but fails locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, memcached

I'm working on an app with a friend and I keep running into errors in my local environment but the app works online (using Heroku). I believe memcache is causing issues in my local environment. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Added the memcache add-on to my app in Heroku
2. Installed Homebrew on my machine
3. Installed memcache using Homebrew with `brew install memcached`

Then I've restarted my app and ran the memcache process with `memcached -vv`.

When I access the app it works fine. Then I'll create a record. This also works fine. Then on page reload - when the record is fetched from the cache, the entire app systematically fails. Below is the error I receive (although I'm not sure how much help it is)

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.empty?
```

The error(s) only point to code where memcache is used. A simple user action (i.e. buy a book from a company) triggers the error and once it occurs the entire app is broken (meaning any route leads to the same error). It seems as though its just not storing/fetching the item, which makes me think the app isn't hitting memcache at all...Is it possible I have to gem install something - even though this is working in the production environment and on another dev's machine?

I'm looking for any guidance with troubleshooting memcache. More specifically, has anyone ever run into issues with local vs. production environments in regards to memcache? Any suggestions? I've thought about removing memcache from the app on Heroku, then un-installing it on my computer and then redoing everything.

I know I'm being fairly vague here but I'm not exactly sure what code to post that would help.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frustration I began retracing the steps I took to install and implement memcache on my local environment. It didn't make sense how it was working online and with my friend's environment but not mine. Eventually I ran `bundle install` and then restarted the app and ran a new memcached process and that fixed everything. I'm still a bit confused but I guess my `Gemfile` just wasn't updated (even though I could've sworn it was).

Answer (score 0):

I use memached without any problems in my environmens, though I do not use Herouku. To access memcached, I have installed the Dalli gem from https://github.com/mperham/dalli

Using it is rather simple.
In the file environment.rb add:

```
DC = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:11211')
```

In the application I use

```
DC.get(key)
DC.delete(key)
DC.set(key,value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think I solved my own problem by running bundle (see explanation above).

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to test if the keys you're setting are actually getting set or not. You can use [Memcached via a Telnet interface](https://wincent.com/wiki/Testing_memcached_with_telnet) to test this.

Comment: I followed the steps in the link and everything seemed to work properly. I was getting desperate and began retracing my steps for installing and implementing memcache locally and at one point I ran bundle install and after restarting the app and restarting a new memcached process it seemed to have fixed it. Not sure exactly what fixed the issue (probably running bundle) but nevertheless the problem is gone. Thank you for the link, I did find the info interesting.